# BehaviorSubject wont update in different route

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, subscription, behaviorsubject

Im fairly new to Angular and am having trouble passing an array to a different (not parent/child related) component on a **different route**. What I want in my app is to click on a button to mark a booking as 'accepted', and to display that same array of accepted bookings in a different view (changing the route).

I've tried implementing a BehaviorSubject but its not working. I can set the array succesfully, but when I want to retrieve it by subscribing to it in the 2nd component, it only shows the initial value of the subject, which in this case is 'Hello World'. Please help me, I've been trying this for a week, watching youtube videos and googling, but I cant find whats wrong.
**PD: I have not added sharedService as a provider in the app.component.ts, if anyone was wondering.**

```
First component
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {SharedService} from '../../services/shared.service';
import {share} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-turnos',
  templateUrl: './turnos.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./turnos.component.css'],
  providers:[TurnoService]
})
export class TurnosComponent implements OnInit {

    public turnos: Turno;
    public status;


  constructor(

    private _sharedService: SharedService

    ) { }


  acceptBooking(booking){

    this._sharedService.addToAccepted(booking);

    this._sharedService.acceptedBookingsSubject.pipe(share()).subscribe(res=>console.log(res));
//this is just to watch the response, which shows the correct array, but it works only in this component
}

}
```

Now, the shared service

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs';
import {Turno} from '../models/turno';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})

export class SharedService{

    private acceptedBookings=[];

    public acceptedBookingsSubject= new BehaviorSubject<any[]>(['Hello World']);



    constructor(){ 
    }

addToAccepted(turno : Turno){

    this.acceptedBookings.push(turno);
    this.acceptedBookingsSubject.next(this.acceptedBookings);   


 }




}
```

And finally, the 2nd component, which has to show all the accepted bookings. I've used both the pipe(share()) using async pipe ,and subscribe() options to see if any worked, but both just show 'Hello World' when I call a console.log.

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {SharedService} from '../../services/shared.service';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {Turno} from '../../models/turno';
import {share} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-turnoaceptado',
  templateUrl: './turnoaceptado.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./turnoaceptado.component.css'],
  providers:[SharedService]
})
export class TurnoaceptadoComponent implements OnInit {

        public acceptedBookings;
        public array:Observable<any[]>;
        public test;

          ngOnInit(): void {

            this.array = this._sharedService.acceptedBookingsSubject.asObservable();

            this.array.subscribe(response=>this.acceptedBookings=response);

            this.test=this.array.pipe(share());

            console.log(this.test);
            console.log(this.acceptedBookings);
  }

  constructor(private _sharedService: SharedService) { }
```

}

Comment: I have a question for better understanding for better answering: When do you first call subscribing in the second component? Normally, you should have subscribed before it is updated according to my experience.

Comment: @LuDeveloper I've tried subscribing in OnInit and inside the constructor, I do not know much about this as Im new to angular. How do I suscribe before updating on a different component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> First of all, since you're providing the service in the root (`provideIn: 'root'`) you need to remove it from the `providers` array from your components and any other module if it's provided there.

When passing data between components using subjects you must keep in mind that you send that data from a component as a payload through the `next` method of the subject but for 'reading' the data you must create a new observable with the subject as the source (`asObservable()` method) as you do in the second component.

In your service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class SharedService{
    private acceptedBookingsSubject= new BehaviorSubject<any[]>(['Hello World']);
    public bookingListener$ = this.acceptedBookingsSubject.asObservable();

    constructor(){ }

    addToAccepted(turno : Turno){
    this.acceptedBookingsSubject.next(turno);   
  }
}
```

In your first component:

```
 acceptBooking(booking) {
   this._sharedService.addToAccepted(booking);  

   // you should move this in the OnInit life cycle hook but you need to remove the take operator or to increase the value
   this._sharedService.bookingListener$
    .pipe(take(1))
    .subscribe(console.log);
}
```

In your second component:

```
public acceptedBookings$: Observable<any[]>;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.acceptedBookings$ = this._sharedService.bookingListener$;

    this.acceptedBookings$.subscribe(console.log);
  }
```

I've created [this stackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g9cdgd) to give you an example. I hope it helps you.

> Tip: Use the `async` pipe for displaying your data and use `tap` operator for side effects instead of manually subscribing in the component.

Comment: I appreciate your answer really much because you actually took the time to write all of this code for me and to even make a stackblitz, but unfortunately its not working if you put the components in different routes, it only works if they are in the same route. Do you perhaps now if what Im trying to achieve is impossible?

Comment: @Ayrton I've updated the stackblitz to demonstrate that the data is passed between components with routing. Give it a try. Maybe I haven't understood correctly what you want to achieve. Can you create a stackblitz with your desired behaviour or fork mine?

Comment: you are right!! I was accesing the route by opening the component directly in another tab instead of clicking on it through a link in the other component! that was the problem! thank you very much <3

Answer (score 0):

The code in your TurnosComponent and SharedService looks correct.

But in your TurnoaceptadoComponent, your 'console.logs' are outside the RXJS stream. You should console.log inside your subscription, like:

`this.array.subscribe(response=> console.log(response));`

Then you should be able to see all the values that comes through the stream.

Comment: I've done it now, but it just shows 'Observable' with lots of things inside, but no values or arrays; and when I click to accept bookings in the other component, the console log stays the same, nothing changes.

Comment: So I do see another potential problem in your code. In your service where you are nexting in the values, you are always passing in a reference to the same array. Try destructuring it like this: this.acceptedBookingsSubject.next( [... this.acceptedBookings] )